# Secure methods storing user data for another website

Tags: security

Im currently working on a cloud based instagramBot,

i have to store Instagram login information in a database, however methods like hash + salt wont work since i still have to login to instagram and wont be able to decode it.

Are there any methods to still maintain security?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use the user's credentials directly. You use OAuth to generate an access token tat grants only the permission you require. Your bot will use that in order to act on the user's behalf.

See Instagram's [Authentication documentation](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/) on how to generate OAuth tokens and assign the correct scope to them.